# Environment variables not working while deploying react app through git-hub actions

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, node-modules, vite, cicd

I am using azure web app service to deploy my react application build through vite.Using git-hub actions for CI/CD. I wanted to use environment variables in my react app which I used as :

```js
import React from 'react';

function Todo() {
  const someKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY;
  

  return (
<div>
  Todo
  {someKey}
  
</div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

1.env file is in root dir (No issues there )

2.env file looks like : VITE_SOME_KEY=123

3.env variabels working great on local server

4.As soon as I deploy my application I can't see my .env variabel values there

5.I have configured app settings and have also added my env variable there

6.Inside Advanced Tools>Environment my env var is listed correctly with correct value

7.Inside configuration file of vite.config.js I have added my env var declaration correctly as:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        globals: {
          
          'import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.VITE_SOME_KEY||'ABC'),
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have done all things correctly gone through docs , stackoverflow but don't know what is going wrong here . My github wokflow file is :

```html
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - my-notes

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      # zip the build directory
      - name: Zip Release
        uses: TheDoctor0/zip-release@0.7.1
        with:
          filename: release.zip
          # Base path for archive files
          path: ./dist/*
          # Working directory before zipping

      
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'my-notes'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_D81356694B8E443E8730CBE89FE4B78A }}
          package: release.zip
```

Please tell me where I am lacking behind .

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work, you can directly add environment variable in your Azure web app Configuration settings like below:-

[image]

Do not make any changes to your vite.config.js file, Directly access the environment variable by adding the variable like above or in your local app folder, Create `.env file` and add the code below:-

```
VITE_SOME_KEY=123
```

In my **app.jsx** I added the code below:-

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import './App.css'
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const someKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_KEY;
  

  return (
    <>
        <div>
      App
      {someKey}
    </div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Vite + React</h1>
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>
          count is {count}
        </button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.jsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </>
  )
  
}
export default App
```

You can also make use of process.env instead of meta.env in your Todo function like below:-

```js
import React from 'react';

function Todo() {
  const someKey = process.env.VITE_SOME_KEY;
  

  return (
    <div>
      Todo
      {someKey}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;
```

**My github repository:-**

[image]

**Azure Web app started Github action workflow like below:-**

[image]

**My github workflow script:-**

```yaml
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - valleywebapp07

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'valleywebapp07'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxx29544B84CF313CA }}
          package: .
```

**Output:-**

[image]